# Is there a good tutorial to mint Cardano NFT using plutus script?

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, nft, minting

I used to mint Cardano NFT using "Time locking" following this guide https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting-nfts/. But I know the more formal way is to use plutus script to mint NFT after the introduction of smart contract. Is there a similar guide on how to achieve this? I know Lars did a tutorial on that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SsaVjSsPPcg. But I am too dumb to follow. Any simplified step-by-step instructions available?

Answer (score 10):

I am answering my own question. After several days of studies and testing, I finally mint NFT using plutus script. Please find my articles below:

https://edwardtam919.medium.com/how-to-mint-cardano-nft-using-smart-contract-part-i-1d75a0398cd2

https://edwardtam919.medium.com/how-to-mint-cardano-nft-using-smart-contract-part-ii-ec7eccc77686

Answer (score 0):

Really interesting stuff.  I believe @Berry put out a sample for how to do this as well on his Github page: https://github.com/Berry-Pool/plutus-contracts/tree/master/NFTSeries