# How to Deploy / Write NFT Minting Plutus Script?

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, nft

I am following through the third cohort PPP. With a week of course break, I wish to consolidate my understanding through practice. One exercise is to go through the deployment process of an NFT:

1. Construct the plutus script (e.g. homework of week 5)
2. Test it on the plutus playground / run the EmulatorTrace
3. Write the plutus file through a script like week 3's `Deploy.hs`.
4. Build & Submit the transaction on testnet

Following through Lars's lecture, there is no problem for step 1-2. However, I got stuck at step 3. The two relevant lines from week 3's `Deploy.hs` should be:

```
writeValidator :: FilePath -> Ledger.Validator -> IO (Either (FileError ()) ())
writeValidator file = writeFileTextEnvelope @(PlutusScript PlutusScriptV1) file Nothing . PlutusScriptSerialised . SBS.toShort . LBS.toStrict . serialise . Ledger.unValidatorScript

writeVestingValidator :: IO (Either (FileError ()) ())
writeVestingValidator = writeValidator "/Users/whatever/Desktop/Plutus-Pioneer-Program/testnet/vesting.plutus" $ validator $ VestingParam
    { beneficiary = Ledger.PaymentPubKeyHash "0d26b900ffa6a3234166ed76467e80fbd8e1f6bad938f75cb884ef6b"
    , deadline    = 1645113135000
    }
```

The logic should be calling the `validator` function from the `Parameterized.hs` at `writeVestingValidator`, then put it in `writeValidator` to output the plutus file. However, it cannot directly copy and paste for week 5's NFT haskell scripts as the `Ledger.unValidatorScript` takes in a `Validator` as parameter while there is no `Validator` type inside the NFT policy script.

I have found `unMintingPolicyScript` in the haddock to replace `unValidatorScript`, but to no avail. My final attempt is like below:

```
writeValidator :: FilePath -> Ledger.Validator -> IO (Either (FileError ()) ())
writeValidator file = writeFileTextEnvelope @(PlutusScript PlutusScriptV1) file Nothing . PlutusScriptSerialised . SBS.toShort . LBS.toStrict . serialise . Ledger.unMintingPolicyScript

writeNFTValidator :: IO (Either (FileError ()) ())
writeNFTValidator = writeValidator "/Users/whatever/Desktop/Plutus-Pioneer-Program/testnet/nft/mint-TokenWithMeta.plutus" $ (policy (Ledger.TxOutRef "f79a3a51ecc200b6ccfdb5d083652787fc3c389a30d9d5b75bcd883428b9c9d5#0") (TokenName "TestNFT"))
```

Sorry its kind of a mess, But somehow I get stuck here.

I have tried to look at different guides, the first is from official Cardano documentation https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting-nfts/. It doesn't solve my doubt as it seems not using plutus script to mint the NFT.

Another guide ([Is there a good tutorial to mint Cardano NFT using plutus script?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/3742/is-there-a-good-tutorial-to-mint-cardano-nft-using-plutus-script)) has a walk through on deploying NFT plutus script, however, it uses a cabal command link `cabal run create-nft-script -- PlutusScriptNFT 6c1160302bff7c84b347e6c9c1cf78cbafc8821efc730f6271589fcd848635f7#0` to serve the purpose. However, I want to perform the `write script` through haskell script so it can be more repeatable when I start building more complex validator or policy.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.